# Getting null values object in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, postman

I have a springboot application where when I am posting a JSON from postman I am getting null values.

**Springboot file:**

```
`package com.learnspringboot.demo.controller;

import com.learnspringboot.demo.entity.Department;
import com.learnspringboot.demo.service.DepartmentService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class DepartmentController {

    @Autowired
    private DepartmentService departmentService;

    @PostMapping("/departments")
    public Department saveDepartment(@RequestBody Department department){
       ** System.out.println(department.toString());**
        return departmentService.saveDepartment(department);
    }

    @GetMapping("/departments")
    public List<Department> fetchDepartment(){
        return departmentService.fetchDepartment();
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/departments/{Id}")
    public String deleteDepartment(@PathVariable("Id") Long DepartmentId){
        departmentService.deleteDepartment(DepartmentId);
        return "Department Id: "+ DepartmentId +" Deleted Successfully";
    }
}
`
```

[Springboot console logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v45fu.png)

[Postman Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mgS3.png)

Any suggestions to resolve this will be highly appreciated.

I tried replacing this with actual IP but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON object you're sending in Postman needs to match the Java object your mapping it to. In your case it will be the `Department` object. It looks like you are sending the fields starting with uppercase which is causing the issue.

try sending the below on postman (note fields are in camel case)

```
{
    "departmentName": "India",
    "departmentCode": "TT",
    "departmentAddress": "001"
}
```